# paypal onboard before payment 403 Forbidden error, issue: MISSING_SCOPES

Tags: paypal, postman

I tried generate a PayPal sign-up link with postman
I get the 403 error
[in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s9mb.png)

I am a paypal partner and I have access token

Answer (score 0):

Contact your partner relationship manager or PayPal's technical support, share your sandbox client ID and the PayPal-Debug-Id from the response headers, and your request/response in text format (not a screenshot), and ask for the required scope(s) on your sandbox application